# How to write SQL Query to pull SCCM Deployment Status based on Maintenance window start time instead of Enforcement deadline

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, sccm

I'm using the below query to pull the deployment status based on the last enforcement deadline(last 24 hours),

```
SELECT vrs.name0
    ,a.EnforcementDeadline
    ,sn.StateName AS LastEnforcementState
FROM v_CIAssignment a
JOIN v_AssignmentState_Combined assc ON a.AssignmentID = assc.AssignmentID
JOIN v_StateNames sn ON assc.StateType = sn.TopicType
    AND sn.StateID = isnull(assc.StateID, 0)
JOIN v_R_System vrs ON vrs.ResourceID = assc.ResourceID
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, a.EnforcementDeadline, getdate()) = 1
```

is it possible to pull the deployment status based on the collection Maintenance window start time ?

Comment: FYI functions like `ISNULL` and `DATEDIFF` aren't SARGable and shouldn't be used in the `WHERE` and `ON` on columns. Use them on other functions, or use proper boolean logic. fr example `(sn.StateID = assc.StateID OR (sn.StateID = 0 AND assc.StateID IS NULL))`. The other clause could be a couple of things, but  `WHERE a.EnforcementDeadline >= DATEADD(DAY, -1,CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) AND a.EnforcementDeadline < CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` will replicate the logic regardless of data types.

Comment: Thank You Larnu, I will update it accordingly.. Now, is it possible to get the deployment status based on the collection maintenance window?

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you.

Comment: This is the query I'm using to get the LastEnforcementState based on EnforcementDeadline 

SELECT vrs.name0
    ,a.EnforcementDeadline
    ,sn.StateName AS LastEnforcementState
FROM v_CIAssignment a
JOIN v_AssignmentState_Combined assc ON a.AssignmentID = assc.AssignmentID
JOIN v_StateNames sn ON assc.StateType = sn.TopicType
    AND sn.StateID = isnull(assc.StateID, 0)
JOIN v_R_System vrs ON vrs.ResourceID = assc.ResourceID
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, a.EnforcementDeadline, getdate()) = 1

Comment: The query I can see, it's above. I can't run that query though, I don't have access to your instance.

Comment: Servername 2020-07-28 03:00:00 Compliant

Comment: I can't connect to your instance... you ***need*** to put the sample data in your question.

Comment: @Vignesh you need to edit your question to include some sample data from your database and what your desired result should look like - a mock up on what you what to achieve with your query. None of us can connect to your datasource or see what you see.So assume nothing!